# Sum deep column values of a multidimensional array and map results to another element in the same array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, sum

I'm experimenting with arrays in PHP and I am setting up a fake environment where a "team's" record is held in arrays.

```
$t1 = array (
    "basicInfo" => array (
        "The Sineps",
        "December 25, 2010",
        "lemonpole"
    ),
    "overallRecord" => array (
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
    ),
    "overallSeasons" => array (
        "season1.cs" => array (0, 0, 0),
        "season2.cs" => array (0, 0, 0)
    ),
    "matches" => array (
        "season1.cs" => array (
            "week1" => array ("12", "3", "1"),
            "week2" => array ("8", "8" ,"0"),
            "week3" => array ("8", "8" ,"0")
        ),
        "season2.cs" => array (
            "week1" => array ("9", "2", "5"),
            "week2" => array ("12", "2" ,"2")
        )
    )
);
```

What I am trying to achieve is to add all the **wins**, **loss**, and **draws** from all weeks of each season to their respective season total.

For example, the sum of all the weeks in `$t1["matches"]["season1.cs"]` will be added to `$t1["overallSeasons"]["season1.cs"]`. The result would leave:

```
"overallSeasons" => array (
    "season1.cs" => array (28, 19, 1),
    "season2.cs" => array (21, 4, 7)
),
```

I tried to work this out on my own for the past hour and all I have gotten is a little more knowledge of **for-loops** and **foreach-loops** . So I think I now have the basics down such as using **foreach** loops and so on. However, I am still fairly new to this so bear with me!

I can get the loop to the point of the `$t1["matches"]` key and go through each season, but I can't seem to figure out how to add all of the **wins**, **loss**, and **draw**, for each individual week.

For now, I'm only looking for answers concerning the overall seasons sum since I can work from there once I figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you're trying to accomplish, havn't tested it though.

```
foreach ($t1['matches'] as $key=>$value){
   $wins = 0;
   $losses = 0;
   $draws = 0;
   foreach($value as $record){
      $wins   += $record[0];
      $losses += $record[1];
      $draws  += $record[2];
   }

   $t1['overallSeasons'][$key] = array($wins, $losses, $draws);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
foreach($t1['matches'] as $season => $season_array) {
        foreach($season_array as $week => $week_array) {
                for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
                        $t1['overallSeasons'][$season][$i] += $week_array[$i];
                }
        }
}
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/Msfrb)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the matches subarray to access the season values.  Then make mapped calls of `array_sum()` on each column of data relating to the parent loop's season value.  This is flexible enough to handle other than 3 columns in the deep rows.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/P85A4))

```
foreach ($t1['matches'] as $season => $weeks) {
    $t1['overallSeasons'][$season] = array_map(
        fn(...$col) => array_sum($col),
        ...array_values($t1['matches'][$season])
    );
}
var_export($t1);
```

---

If this technique is too hard to follow, then the equivalent would be 2 classic loops.  The inner loop can safely use array destructuring on the week data because only 3-element rows will ever be encountered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WF5Hm))

```
foreach ($t1['matches'] as $season => $weeks) {
    foreach ($weeks as [$w, $l, $d]) {
        $t1['overallSeasons'][$season][0] += $w;
        $t1['overallSeasons'][$season][1] += $l;
        $t1['overallSeasons'][$season][2] += $d;
    }
}
var_export($t1);
```